# キーを押してから徐々にボリュームを上げていく方法がわかりません

Tags: c#, unity3d

KeyCode.Wを押してから徐々にAudioSource.volumeを `3f` まで上げて行きたいのですが
現状のコードではフリーズしてしまいます。

どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private float volumeWhile = 3f;
  
    void Start()
    {
  
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                while (audioSource.volume < volumeWhile)
                {
                    audioSource.Play();
                    audioSource.volume += 0.5f;

                    if (audioSource.volume == volumeWhile) break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りをメインにしているので、英語の併記は不要です。

Answer (score 0):

`while` 文が `break` する条件で「目標の値になったら」ということで `==` での比較を行っていますが、浮動小数点同士の比較なので演算 (ここではインクリメント) をしていく過程で **誤差** が発生している可能性があります。

代わりに「目標の値を超えたら」にしてみると良いかもしれません。

```
if (audioSource.volume >= volumeWhile) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

[【Unity】キーを押してから徐々にボリュームを上げていく方法がわかりません。](https://teratail.com/questions/e32vuboauda7xj) ではコルーチンでないものを使って問題がクローズされているので、こちらに書いておきます。なお、[AudioSource.volume の最大値は 1](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2019.4/ScriptReference/AudioSource-volume.html) です。

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float _changeVolumeDelta = 0.001f;
    [SerializeField] float _changeVolumeIntervalSecond = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] float _maxVolume = 1;
    AudioSource _audio = default;
    Coroutine _coroutine = default;

    void Start()
    {
        _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            // 音が「流れていない」時
            if (!_audio.isPlaying)
            {
                if (_coroutine != null)
                {
                    _coroutine = StartCoroutine(IncreaseVolume(_maxVolume));
                }
            }
        }

        // ↓を押している間、ボリュームを下げる
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            _coroutine = StartCoroutine(DecreaseVolume());
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            StopCoroutine(_coroutine);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IncreaseVolume(float target)
    {
        while (_audio.volume < target)
        {
            _audio.volume += _changeVolumeDelta;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_changeVolumeIntervalSecond);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DecreaseVolume()
    {
        while (_audio.volume > 0)
        {
            _audio.volume -= _changeVolumeDelta;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_changeVolumeIntervalSecond);
        }
    }
}
```